# MobileMe bookmark sync with Opera

Tags: mobileme, opera

I am forced to use Opera instead of Safari on windows, and would like to sync my bookmarks with MobileMe. Is this at all possible?

Comment: The real question is why aren't you using opera on the mac. Opera is way more powerful than safari.

Answer (score 2):

Not with MobileMe's built in sync function, it only works with Safari.

You could use Opera's Link, which might work ok for what you're after -

> Can I use other browsers to access my bookmarks?
>
> Yes, you can log into a web-based user interface using Opera browsers, including Opera for Mac/PC, Opera Mobile or Opera Mini. You can also access your bookmarks using other Web browsers like Internet Explorer, Firefox or Safari. ([Opera faq](http://www.opera.com/link/faq/))

Answer (score 0):

Like dropbox, you could simlink the Opera bookmark file into your iDisk. Something like ln -s /Users/.../bookmark.dat /Volumes/iDisk/bookmark.dat

If you want cross-browser bookmark sync - wait for xmarks or similar to come to both of those browsers, so far ti's probably only firefox and chrome.

Comment: xMarks works fine with Safari, if you don't mind system preference plugins.